# Fastest permutations implementation in Python

Tags: python

I have the following implementation for permutation generation in python:

```
def perms(v):
    '''
    Generates permutations for sequence v
    :param v: sequence for permutations
    '''
    if not v:
        yield ()
    else:
        for p in perms(v[1:]):
            for i in range(len(v)):
                yield p[:i] + (v[0],) + p[i:]
```

It works faster than itertools.permutations (it also does less, I know). Is there a faster (or alternatively more compact) implementation. I tried implementing it with vector insert/delete and it seems slower.

Comment: `s/iterable/sequence/g`

Comment: Agreed. But it does not make it any faster... :-)

Comment: Instead of slicing `v` you can use a start index. This should avoid the memory allocation which might help a bit with performances.

Comment: I've compared it to `itertools.permutations` and your implementation is between 4 and 10 times slower. For what input is it faster than the itertools implementation?

Comment: I must second jorgeca. I just tried with an input of length 8 and `itertools.permutations` is 25 times faster. (my suggestion doesn't seem to improve the *time* performances; it's almost as fast as before, but it reduces the additional memory usage from O(n^2) to O(n))

Comment: Ouch. Yes you are correct. I did an incorrect measurement. Actually I wanted to find a fast solution to N-Queens problem, so I used something like 'cProfile.run('s=next(sols1)')
print(s)             
cProfile.run('s=next(sols2)')
print(s)             '. It's just a wrong way to measure it.

Comment: @Bakuriu. And you are correct using start index will at least reduce memory. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("sum([1 for i in permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])])", setup="from itertools import permutations", number=1000)
0.0829811965812155

>>> timeit.timeit("sum([1 for i in perms([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])])", setup="from test import perms", number=1000)
0.4672438746438843
```

it looks like your implementation is more than 5 times slower on this simple example. Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe that to profile generators it's better to use `from collections import deque; deque(the_generator(), 0)` since this is the fastest way to consume an iterable and it also doesn't consume extra memory and doesn't perform additional operations on the results. In this specific case use `deque` is about 4 times faster than using `sum`.